# Numer of binary digits of a power of ten (from Weissman's “An Illustrated Theory of Numbers”)

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

I have been working through the following exercise (chapter $0$, number $17$, in Weissman's *An Illustrated Theory of Numbers*):

> How many bits does the binary expansion of $10^{500}$ have?

I know the number of binary digits is $\lfloor 500 \cdot \log_2 10 \rfloor + 1$, so I can get the answer with a calculator.

Could I know how many bits the binary expansion of $10^{500}$ has, without a calculator or a logarithmic table? Does it help that this exercise considers the number of binary digits of a power of $10$?

It's easy to observe that $10^{500} = 5^{500} \cdot 2^{500}$, so its binary expansion ends with $500$ zeros. Then, I used the following factorization of $5^{500} - 1$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
5^{500} - 1 &= (5^{250} + 1) (5^{250} - 1) = (5^{250} + 1) (5^{125} + 1) (5^{125} - 1) \\
&= (5^{250} + 1) (5^{125} + 1) (5 - 1) (5^{124} + \ldots + 5 + 1).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Therefore, the largest power of $2$ dividing $5^{500} - 1$ is $2^4$ and the binary expansion of $5^{500}$ ends with $10001$. But I can't get any further.

Comment: If we knew the answer, say that it is $k$ digits, we'd know that $k\le500\log_2 10<k+1$. In other words, we'd know that $$\frac k{500}\le\log_2{10}<\frac k{500}+0.02$$ That is, your problem is equivalent to find the second digit of $\log_2{10}$ with a $\pm1$ error.

Comment: @ajotatxe As $\frac 1{500}=0.002$ you need the third digit of $\log_2 10$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you know that $\log_{10}2 \approx 0.30103$.  We have $\log_2{10}=\frac 1{\log_{10}2}\approx \frac 1{0.30103}$.  Doing the inversion is just a long division, which is quite possible without a calculator.

To compute $\log_2 (10)$ you can start with $\log_2(10)=3+\log_2(1.25)$.  Take successive square roots of $2$ by hand and find the first one less than $1.25$.  It will be $2^{1/4}$, so $\log_2(10)=3.25+\log_2(\frac {1.25}{2^{1/4}})$  You can keep going until you get the accuracy you need.  You need it within about $0.002$.  It will be some work, but you can get there.  Tables are wonderful things.